# Spark Java ClassNotFound

Tags: java, module, classloader, spark-java, urlclassloader

I'm coding an application which is module based, so it loads other jar files into the classpath. One module of this application is a RestAPI. For the RestAPI I'm using Spark Java. Now my problem is, that one class is not able to be loaded.
The Exception looks as following:

```
org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pac4j.core.profile.CommonProfile
```

I actually shaded the class into my jar.

What I tried yet:

I tried to load it manually by Class#forName. This did actually not throw an exception. I tried to load the whole jar file using an URLClassLoader. Nothing worked.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Which dependency management system (if any) are you using?

Comment: I'm actually using maven, and the dependency management seems absolutely fine. I have already decompiled my own jar file and everything is where it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Download this package from bellow link :-

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/pac4j/pac4j-core/2.0.0/pac4j-core-2.0.0.jar

Or

If you're using a dependency manager (Maven, SBT, Ivy, Gradle, etc.) copy and paste the respective dependency. If you're using a dependency manager, that's all there is to resolving this exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i actually know how to use maven. But the problem is actually probably the classloader because I have developed a modular application.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency property in your pom.xml if you are using maven build tool.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>pac4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This will resolve your problem. If you are facing the same problem again then navigate to `~/.m2/repository/org/pac4j` directory delete all the dependencies downloaded and rebuild your project again.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar problem but i solved following Dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```